# Rewrite a multidimensional array to match format of another multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say that I have a multidimensional array that looks like so:

```
{
    "hello" : "world",
    "foo" : {
        "foo": {
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    },
    "some" : "value",
    "other" : {
        "other" : "value"
    }
}
```

And I want to go through this array and change the structure/values/format of it to match a format based on this skeleton array:

```
{
    "hello" : "",
    "foo" : "",
    "some" : {
        "some" : ""
    }
}
```

So that the final output would look like so:

```
{
    "hello" : "world",
    "foo" : "bar",
    "some" : {
        "some" : "value"
    }
}
```

I've used array_intersect_key() to remove extra fields that don't exist in the skeleton array, followed by array_replace_recursive() to add fields that are missing in the initial data-set but exist in the skeleton array.

But I have no idea how I would go about making sure that entries that exist in both the initial data and the skeleton array match the structure of the skeleton.

Can something like this be done in (possibly a recursive) loop that can traverse the initial data and figure out on it's own how to rewrite whatever key/value it's looking at, ***without*** hard coding anything like:

```
if($key1 == "some") {
    $final["some"]["some"] = $initial["some"];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand exactly. I mean you like to resolve same named keys and compress them to one level. But why do you have then two times `some` afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's possible but only if we assume that you find the first occurrence of key from your array. Otherwise it may be really hard to find values if they are plenty of them.

For example for this code:

```
<?php

$in
    = [
    "hello" => "world",
    "foo"   => [
        "foo" => [
            "foo" => "bar"
        ]
    ],
    "some"  => "value",
    "other" => [
        "other" => "value"
    ]
];

$out
    = [
    "hello" => "",
    "foo"   => "",
    "some"  => [
        "some" => ""
    ]
];


var_dump(fill($in, $out));


function fill($in, $out)
{
    foreach ($out as $k => $v) {
        if (!is_array($v)) {
            $out[$k] = find($in, $k);
        } else {
            $out[$k] = fill($in, $v);
        }
    }
    return $out;
}

function find($array, $needle)
{
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (!is_array($v)) {
            if ($k == $needle) {
                return $v;
            }
        } else {

            $result = find($v, $needle);
            if ($result !== false) {
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

you will get:

> array(3) { ["hello"]=> string(5) "world" ["foo"]=> string(3) "bar"
>   ["some"]=> array(1) { ["some"]=> string(5) "value" } }

so the same as you expected but you should test it before more general usage if it will work in all cases. If the same key hasn't been found you get `false` result.